# List comprehension vs. for loop performance testing

Tags: python, list, performance

In an effort to avoid Django ModelSerialization performance hits, I am looking at "serializing" a result set on my own. Many related Stackoverflow questions say that list comprehension should be the fastest, but my own tests are showing nested for loops being consistently faster.

I have raw DB results (100) that need to be converted into a list of OrderedDict based on an ordered list of fields (14). Is my use case too complex for the list comprehension performance advantage, or my sample size too small? Maybe the performance is negligible? My overall question is: am I going about testing the performance properly?

**Nested for-loop (0.000919342041015625)**

```py
serialized = []
start = time.time()
for raw in results:
    result = OrderedDict()
    for index, field in enumerate(fields):
        result[field] = raw[index]
    serialized.append(result)
end = time.time()
print("For loop + for loop " + str(end - start))
```

**Nested list comprehension (0.011911153793334961)**

```py
serialized = []
start = time.time()
serialized = [OrderedDict((field, raw[index]) for index, field in enumerate(fields)) for raw in results]
end = time.time()
print("List comprehensions + list comprehensions " + str(end - start))
```

**For-loop + list comprehension (0.020151615142822266)**

```py
serialized = []
start = time.time()
for raw in results:
    result = OrderedDict((field, raw[index]) for index, field in enumerate(fields))
    serialized.append(result)
end = time.time()
print("For loop + list comprehensions " + str(end - start))
```

Comment: What is the question? We have no way of running this code (there is no [mre]) and you seem to have timings so the answer is there...

Comment: `serialized = [OrderedDict([(field, rawi) for rawi, field in zip(raw, fields)]) for raw in results]`

Comment: But regardless, (a) the timings are likely not significant at all; and (b) performance is often overrated compared to removing boilerplate code and reusability.

Comment: Well if for loop is fastest, and at least to my eye the most readable, I would go with that (as I also am not sure of question).

Comment: List comprehensions *are not for performance*. "Research says that list comprehension should be the fastest" any performance gains from list comprehensions are *marginal*.

Comment: The fundamental problem here though is that while you are using a list comprehension (which you might expect some modest benefit if the work done inside is really small, e.g. `x + 1`), you are using a generator expression to create the orderd dict: `OrderedDict((field, raw[index]) for index, field in enumerate(fields)` and generator expressions are usually slower (more overhead per iteration) than a plain loop.

Comment: I suspect you'll get the best timings if you create a helper function to do the work inside your inner loop, then use `serialized = [create_ordered_dict(raw, fields) for raw in results]`

Comment: "For-loop + list comprehension (0.020151615142822266)" there is actually no list comprehension there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is my use case too complex for the list comprehension performance advantage, or my sample size too small? Maybe the performance is negligible?

You here measure *wall time*, not *CPU* time, this makes results (very) unreliable. Indeed, if the program for example is suspended by the operating system and resumed a few microseconds later, then you will thus see aspects that have nothing to do with it.

In order to benchmark effectively, you need to *repeat* the same experiment multiple times, and try to measure *CPU* time. We can for example use `%timeit` of `ipython` which will repeat the experiment multiple times. Then we get:

```
In [1]: vals = [list(range(10)) for _ in range(100)]

In [2]: fields = [f'field_{i}' for i in range(10)]

In [3]: from collections import OrderedDict

In [4]: %timeit [OrderedDict((field, val[index]) for index, field in enumerate(fields)) for val in vals]
239 µs ± 2.24 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

In [5]: %timeit [OrderedDict(zip(fields, val)) for val in vals]
146 µs ± 4.8 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
```

This would thus be the case for hundred records, each with ten fields.

That being said, the *time complexity* will be the same, so it will both scale in the same order. Furthermore people often focus too much on performance compared to making elegant and reusable code. Indeed, the `ModelSerializer` will likely not serialize in the most effective way, but that was never its aim. The aim of the serializer is to work *bi-directional*: serializing data, but also deserializing data into objects again. To validate data and clean it, and to make it more clear *what* will happen, and not so much how that will happen. It also makes it easy to mark fields as readonly.

The aim of Python is therefore not to achieve the best performance, but to offer *programmer convenience*. Often performance is not the main problem, but developing a program in a short amount of time. Often developers are more costly than processing power nowadays (especially if N+1 problems, etc. are resolved), and therefore focussing on a few microseconds more or less tends not to pay off.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed performance explanation! 

Yes Django was a design decision for ease of getting things set up many years ago... and now of course the performance is atrocious (to be expected) for certain functions, like searching.